# Wordpress - need help finding a section of code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a website for my band that I'm trying to tidy up. I used to write the entire site but a couple of years ago I decided to go with Wordpress and modify a theme that I purchased.

I have a good understanding of php and MySQL and the site contains a diary system that I wrote myself - the 'gigs' page displays a php include for the public details of the gigs from my database.

My problem is that, on the home page there is a box bottom right of the page that shows a summary of the gigs to come - this doesn't run from my database, this is built into the theme and requires me to manually enter gig details every time the data changes - I really want to display a 'top 5' of my gig list include here but I can't find the section of code within the theme files - I've contacted the developer and asked the question and even offered to help develop the theme so that my code becomes part of the theme and the theme would therefore provide dynamic information, but the developer isn't interested and doesn't want to help me find the code section.

The website is here...
[Captain Obvious Band](http://www.captainobviousobviously.co.uk)

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: How do you enter the gig dates now? Is it a widget? A pagebuilder block?

Comment: It's a basic php/MySQL script that I wrote about 5 years ago - I include it on custom pages for the 'admin' area - the gigs page is a widget that a created.

Comment: I mean the Upcoming Gigs bit on the homepage, not the gigs page.  You said that you manually enter the gig dates for that box, how do you do that?

Comment: Ah ok - these are put on through WP-admin, a section called 'events' that looks like a custom post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98802/discussion-between-objective-d-and-dazzathedrummer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look first of all I cant till you the name of the files by look at the website ...

my suggestion for you

1. search in the files for "home-event-items" its the ID of the block 
   then remove the block and use its html

   ```
       <ul style="margin: 0;" class="one-third" id="home-event-items">                 
           <!-- PROJECT ITEM STARTS -->
           <li data-type="" data-id="id-1905" class="event-home-item ">
               <div class="event-date">
                    22 <br> <strong>Aug </strong> <br>2015                                    
               </div>
               <div class="event-title"><h5>
                       <a title="The Pig n Falcon, St Neots" href="http://www.captainobviousobviously.co.uk/event/details/the-pig-n-falcon-st-neots-6/"> The Pig n Falcon, St Neots </a>
               </h5></div>
               <div class="event-venue">
                   The Pig n Falcon                                    
               </div>
               <div class="ticket-button">
                   <div class="event-cancel-out"><p>Free Entry</p></div>                                    
               </div>
           </li>
           <!-- EVENTS ITEM ENDS -->
       </ul>
   ```